# Get parent object based on child of child criteria and include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Ok so here is a quick version of my tables.

```
public class Line
{
  // Bunch Of properties
  // ...
  public List<Tool> Tools {get;set;}
}

public class Tool
{
  // Bunch Of properties
  // ...
  public List<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}

public class Task
{
  // Bunch Of properties
  // ...
  public List<SchedItem> SchedItems {get;set;}
}

public class SchedItem
{
  public DateTime SchedDate {get;set;}
}
```

What I want is a query that will return all the `Lines` including child collections and their child collections etc based on whether `SchedItem.SchedDate` falls within a date range.

I tried the following in LinqPad.

```
var line = (from p in Lines.Include(x => x.Tools.Select(m => m.Tasks.Select(s => s.SchedItems)))
                        from t in p.Tools
                        from m in t.Tasks
                        from s in m.SchedItems
                        where s.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery &&
                              s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery 
                        select p);
```

This seems wrong to me as the returned data is including all `SchedItems` not just the ones based on the query.

UPDATE 1:
Yeah I think I have my understanding wrong. I have set the following on my context configuration

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

When I run the code again I get a list of 33 `Line` items with no child items. There should only be 1 'Line' item with many child items.

I changed my query to this and I now get the child items but the `Line` count is still 33 which is wrong.

```
var line = (from p in Lines
                        from t in p.Tools
                        from m in t.Tasks
                        from s in m.SchedItems
                        where s.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery &&
                              s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery 
                        select p).Include(x => x.Tools.Select(m => m.Tasks.Select(s => s.SchedItems)));
```

Comment: I think this has been asked many times. Eager loading loads **entities**. It's all or nothing. e.g. when loaded, `Task.ShedItems` contains all the items because this is the case from the **entity** standpoint. If you want to apply filtering, then you are supposed to use projection and not `Include` (which is ignored in such scenarios).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var lines = Lines.Where(i => 
    i.Tools.Any(t => 
        t.Tasks.Any(y => 
            y.SchedItems.Any(u => 
                u.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery  && 
                s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery 
            ) 
        )
    )
);

lines.ForEach(i => new 
{
    i.Tools = i.Tools.Where(t => 
                t.Tasks.Any(y => 
                    y.SchedItems.Any(u => 
                        u.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery  && 
                        s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery 
                    ) 
                )
            );
    i.Tools.ForEach(t => new
    {
        t.Tasks = t.Tasks.Where(y => 
                        y.SchedItems.Any(u => 
                            u.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery  && 
                            s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery 
                        ) 
                    );
    });
});
```

Comment: see my response to @Kedrzu

Comment: @Kedrzu just tried a copy and paste and the first error I got was with `lines.Foreach` as visual studio is saying it could not resolve the `foreach`

Comment: Not `Foreach` It is `ForEach`. Misspellings

Comment: ok made the change and the whole `ForEach` part has red underlining. Hovering over I see most of the errors are `Ìnvalid anonymous type member declarator`

Comment: Use `Select(p => new Tools {...})` in assignments

Answer (score 1):

Your code make cartesian product because of couple `from` statements.
I'll skip configuration of DbContext and assume that you have enabled lazy loading. Try this:

```
var line = from p in ls
           where p.Tools
                .Any(to=> to.Tasks
                    .Any(ta=> ta.SchedItems
                       .Any(s=> s.SchedDate >= StartDateQuery && s.SchedDate <= EndDateQuery)));
           select p;
```

Another way to accomplish your goal is to add parrent to: SchedItem, Task, Tool, find SchedItems that meet your requirements and navigate through parents to Line. For more information go [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations)

Comment: Just tried this and it has solved the issue of returning the correct number of `Line` items. Problem I still have is that I need it to include the relevant child items. Also, when I expand the child items in LinqPad, I get down to the `SchedItems`and I see it has included all the items, not just the ones based on the  `SchedDate`criteria